# Table join working weirdly in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, csv, attribute-joins

I am trying to join a .shp (polygon) with a .csv table containing numerical values. My key is `"Agenzia"` which is in both cases a string field. The join works except for the two values shown in the picture below

[image]

These are the data for the same entries in my .csv table:

[image]

[image]

I'm a bit confused about what's going on here exactly. The names in the two tables are exactly the same (I literally copy/pasted the name from the .shp db to the .csv, so there's no way they are different).

I tried deleting and re-uploading the .csv as well but nothing changes. It doesn't seem to be a NULL error to me, its like the join IS working but not with the correct data?

UPDATE: I realized the #N/A is a value I had on a previous version of the same .csv that I had uploaded on QGIS. The .csv has now different values (the ones you see in the screenshots). So it's like the join isn't reading the updated version of the table for some reason?

Comment: Did you bring both CSV and shapefile with correct encoding in QGIS?

Comment: You seem to have already make sure of that but you can double check that there are not  a trailing space in either the SHP or CSV.  Another idea could be to check both of the font encoding as you have special character (not sure how that would play but till someone have better idea...)

Comment: @Taras yes, the .shp was generated directly by QGIS using a plugin (ORStools), while the .csv is in UTF-8

Comment: @J.R i don't really know how i can check the font encoding, any suggestion on how to do it? anyways i did check the presence of trailing space. to be fair i dont think there's a problem with the matching of the key because the value i get (N/A) isn't something that qgis generated -- admittedly thinking about it this is the value i had on a previous version of the .csv, so its like qgis isnt reading the updated vers? (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) @J.R but the .csv table on qgis is updated, just the join isnt? im a bit confused to be fair

Comment: When you set a join in layer properties there is a pre-checked "Cache join layer in memory" setting. If you update your CSV after setting the join you should uncheck that (you probably need to remove and re-add your join)

Comment: @J.R thank you, this seems to have solved the problem! :)